# How to make HTML elements slide up into place automatically

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make three or four inline elements slide up into place when the user scrolls down to the position they will be.

How do I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello Mach2tv, welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried so far? What does your code looks like? Please take a look, when you can, on how to ask a good question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask